# How do I set up PhpStorm so that the Docker Compose Interpreter can use the PHP executable?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, phpstorm

I'm trying to integrate Docker with PhpStorm by following [this JetBrainsTV video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7aGWO6K3Ho). (The container is working fine - it's up and running).

At the CLI Interpreter edit screen, it says PHP is not installed.

[image]

When I click the synchronise button, I get an 'Address in use' error.

[image]

Comment: what image are you using? Are you able to connect to docker image and check `php --version` outside of PhpStorm? Did you try to provide a full path to php (e.g. /usr/lib/php)?

Comment: @Ástþór I have just seen your comment. I am using Devilbox and the `php-fpm-7.0` docker image. I tried using `/usr/bin/php` (`which php` directs there). The docker image works fine, I can load up web pages as normal, use xdebug etc. If I `echo phpversion` or run `php -v` in the container I get 7.0.23

Comment: Looking good indeed. You can try to submit this at JetBrains tracker for a detailed review: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI#newissue=yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to have the php executable be found simply by changing the service from bind to php, and also ensuring the containers (devilbox runs multiple) were not running.

[image]

I have further questions about how to run, say, a functional test. At present that is not working since it needs devilbox/docker containers to be running.

Comment: did you succeed to run an interpreter of the container?

Comment: @ПавелВайсберг  I'll get back to you on that.